# installing flutter in linux/CentOS7 vagrant VM issues [vagrant@localhost ~]$ flutter doctor -v

Tags: flutter, jenkins, vagrant, devops

Please let me know how to fix this in my vagrant centos vm ssh :

(purpose : jenkins pipeline for flutter web build and FTP deployment on centos7 virtual machine using vagrant ssh access)

***PS: I'm using flutter version 3.7.9 stable • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1***

so, I ran into this first issue I was able to fix it but after ran into more issues :

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ flutter doctor -v
Flutter failed to write to a file at "/opt/flutter/version".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current
user.
Try running:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/flutter/version



#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _throwFileSystemException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:840:3)
#2      _handlePosixException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:767:3)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:610:7)
#4      ErrorHandlingFile.writeAsStringSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:270:5)
#5      FlutterVersion.ensureVersionFile (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart:169:74)
#6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

So this seems to be related to file permissions for Flutter in my Vagrant CentOS VM. The error message indicates that Flutter failed to write to a file at "/opt/flutter/version" and suggests using "sudo chown" to change the ownership of the directory to the current user.

To fix this issue, I did follow the advice given in the error message and ran the suggested command to change ownership of the "/opt/flutter" directory:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/flutter
```

So, This command will recursively change the ownership of all files and subdirectories inside "/opt/flutter" to the currently logged-in user, granting you read/write permissions.

After running the command, I could verify the ownership that has been changed by checking the permissions of the "/opt/flutter/version" file and ensuring it's accessible for your user. To do this, I ran the following command:

```
ls -l /opt/flutter/version
```

So, I should see the owner of the file listed as my current user, and the permissions should allow read and write access for the owner.

Once I have fixed the permissions, I tried running the "flutter doctor -v" command again to see if the issue has been resolved, and It was solved correctly ✅.

Now I got a new issue when running `flutter doctor -v` :

I tried these commands from the flutter documentation (https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#additional-linux-requirements) but I didn't have apt-get package in CentOS, I have only yum install....etc

I need help with this command and how to run it on centos 7 :

`sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev liblzma-dev`

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ flutter doctor -v
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
Resolving dependencies in ../../opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools... (4.1s)
  _fe_analyzer_shared 50.0.0 (62.0.0 available)
  analyzer 5.2.0 (6.0.0 available)
  archive 3.3.2 (3.3.7 available)
  args 2.3.1 (2.4.2 available)
  async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
  built_value 8.4.2 (8.6.1 available)
  checked_yaml 2.0.1 (2.0.3 available)
  collection 1.17.0 (1.17.2 available)
  completion 1.0.0 (1.0.1 available)
  coverage 1.6.1 (1.6.3 available)
  crypto 3.0.2 (3.0.3 available)
  csslib 0.17.2 (1.0.0 available)
  dds 2.5.0 (2.9.2 available)
  dds_service_extensions 1.3.1 (1.6.0 available)
  devtools_shared 2.18.0 (2.25.0 available)
  dwds 16.0.2+1 (19.0.2 available)
  file 6.1.4 (7.0.0 available)
  fixnum 1.0.1 (1.1.0 available)
  frontend_server_client 3.1.0 (3.2.0 available)
  glob 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
  html 0.15.1 (0.15.4 available)
  http 0.13.5 (1.1.0 available)
  intl 0.17.0 (0.18.1 available)
  io 1.0.3 (1.0.4 available)
  js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
  json_annotation 4.7.0 (4.8.1 available)
  logging 1.1.0 (1.2.0 available)
  matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.16 available)
  meta 1.8.0 (1.9.1 available)
  mime 1.0.2 (1.0.4 available)
  multicast_dns 0.3.2+2 (0.3.2+3 available)
  native_stack_traces 0.5.2 (0.5.6 available)
  node_preamble 2.0.1 (2.0.2 available)
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  petitparser 5.1.0 (5.4.0 available)
  pub_semver 2.1.3 (2.1.4 available)
  pubspec_parse 1.2.1 (1.2.3 available)
  shelf 1.4.0 (1.4.1 available)
  shelf_packages_handler 3.0.1 (3.0.2 available)
  shelf_proxy 1.0.2 (1.0.4 available)
  shelf_static 1.1.1 (1.1.2 available)
  shelf_web_socket 1.0.3 (1.0.4 available)
  source_maps 0.10.11 (0.10.12 available)
  source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
  sse 4.1.1 (4.1.2 available)
  stack_trace 1.11.0 (1.11.1 available)
  stream_channel 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
  test 1.22.0 (1.24.4 available)
  test_api 0.4.16 (0.6.1 available)
  test_core 0.4.20 (0.5.4 available)
  typed_data 1.3.1 (1.3.2 available)
  usage 4.1.0 (4.1.1 available)
  vm_service 9.4.0 (11.8.0 available)
  vm_snapshot_analysis 0.7.2 (0.7.6 available)
  watcher 1.0.2 (1.1.0 available)
  web_socket_channel 2.2.0 (2.4.0 available)
  webdriver 3.0.1 (3.0.2 available)
  xml 6.2.2 (6.3.0 available)
  yaml 3.1.1 (3.1.2 available)
Got dependencies in ../../opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools!
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.9, on CentOS Linux 7 (Core) 3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.7.9 on channel stable at /opt/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 62bd79521d (4 months ago), 2023-03-30 10:59:36 -0700
    • Engine revision ec975089ac
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✗] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
    • cmake version 2.8.12.2
    ✗ cmake 3.10.0 or later is required.
    ✗ ninja is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install ninja-build), or can be downloaded from
      https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases
    • pkg-config version 0.27.1
    ✗ pkg-config 0.29.0 or later is required.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • CentOS Linux 7 (Core) 3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.

[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

I tried on my own to fix this but I couldn't that's why I need help

Answer (score 0):

First :

```
sudo yum update
```

The EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository provides additional packages not available in the default CentOS repositories. To install it, run:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

you can try this command but I doubt it would give you specific version for what you need :

```
sudo yum install clang cmake ninja-build pkgconfig gtk3-devel xz-devel
```

```
sudo yum install python-pip
```

to check the version:

```
pip --version
```

for version 3 :

```
sudo yum install python3
```

to check the version :

```
python3 --version
```

https://pypi.org/project/cmake/3.11.0/

```
pip install cmake==3.11.0
```

for other / higher versions check this link then click any version you like and you will see the pip installation command (just copy : https://pypi.org/project/cmake/#history

Install pkgconfig :

```
pip install pkgconfig==1.1.0
```

You can find more info here : https://pypi.org/project/pkgconfig/1.1.0/

version check :

```
pkg-config --version
```

if you ran into pip version issues, use this to upgrade :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
sudo yum install python3-pip
```

```
pip3 --version
```

then repeat the *pkg-config* installation command

Install GTK 3.0 development libraries:

```
sudo yum install gtk3-devel
```